# Resize iSCSI LUN from Linux Client

Tags: iscsi

I have a Linux workstation with an iSCSI LUN mapped on the directory `/mnt/nas509`
the LUN is on `/dev/sdb` and with a partition `/dev/sdb1`
I expand it by the NAS Web Interface, and execute this command on the linux workstation:

```
sudo growpart /dev/sdb 1
```

Now the partition seems correctly expanded but I keep seeing 1.0 TB instead of 1.5TB.
`fdisk /dev/sdb` with command F (show unallocated space) shows 0.

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.5 TiB, 1610612736000 bytes, 3145728000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 1048576 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe6af84e5
```

**/etc/fstab**

```
UUID=166030333DFC9F33 /mnt/nas509 ntfs _netdev 0 0
```

**df -h**

```
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                           974M     0  974M   0% /dev
tmpfs                          200M  972K  199M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/urbackup--vg-root   29G  5.6G   22G  21% /
tmpfs                          996M     0  996M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                          996M     0  996M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                      472M  130M  319M  29% /boot
/dev/sdb1                     1000G  216G  785G  22% /mnt/nas509
```

Comment: You've expanded the partition, now you need to expand the filesystem - not sure which exact linux you're on but usually the resize2fs command is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only changed the size of the LUN, plus the partition of that disk. (Some tools do this in one step but definitely not `growpart`.) Extend the file system.

```
fsadm resize /dev/disk/by-uuid/166030333DFC9F33
```

`fsadm` supports a couple popular file system types, but not ntfs as you have. Same task, different tool:

```
ntfsresize /dev/disk/by-uuid/166030333DFC9F33
```